# Bootstrap Popover Arrow is Misplaced

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty standard usage of the Bootstrap Popover Tooltip. Any idea why the formatting is off on the arrow?

```
 <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <a id="pop" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<%= user.experience.description + ' Average ' + user.experience.name + ' Developer rate is ' + user.experience.hourly_range %>"><%= image_tag('question.png', :class=>"question") %></a>
 </div>
```

.

```
$(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            'placement': 'top'
        });
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            trigger: 'hover',
                'placement': 'top'
        });


});
```

[image: demonstration]

Comment: Do you have some custom sizing CSS in play?

Comment: "Pretty standard" if it was standard, it would work like it does on the bootstrap examples. Please link to your code.

Comment: Here's a link to the page where you can see the error: https://getdev-staging.herokuapp.com/ .  Let me know what else to provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for that issue:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13718

Answer (score 0):

Specify body as a container for the tooltip:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  container: 'body'
});
```